# SQlite Databse update not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have decided to update my app and its database, but after executing the code below and running the app, I get database copied in a strange way - some parts are copied, some are not.

What confuses me the most is that everyting works perfectly on the emulator while on my Nexus the problem occurs.

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        copyDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database" + e.toString());
    }
}

public void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely it would be better to be doing SELECT * and dumping them into the new database by storing them in a temp location first rather than this way. What happens if you change your table schema?

Also, isn't this opening the file and overwriting it as you go along? `outfilename` looks the same as the DB path.

Comment: You're guys really awesome. i have realized that i've changed my table schema in the meantime and when i came back to previous version, everything started working properly. Can You please explain me what's going on?

Comment: Don't think of the database as 'flat file' storage which has your rows in it. There is a lot of meta information contained within the .db file (see http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html for a look at exactly what). You're not interested in storing this meta information, which is actually what the problem is, which is why I recommended dumping the actual *data* instead.

Comment: could you please provide me some android code, 'cause my app crashes during opening database.. i get "database disk image is malformed"? surely get Your idea, but not familiar with implementatin. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

your offset is always 0.

so you're always copying the first 1024 bytes of `myinput`